# Asp.Net Core : Compress the image using ImageSharp and save to database using Blob

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I tried to compress the image using Imagesharp Nuget package and save to my sql database as a Blob file but the problem is image is compressed successfully.. but **not the compressed image only store Original one**,
Example: Pictureone.jpg image size is 3mb..after uploading the image size is compressed like 40kb but when i applied to save in database that compressed file its save original one (3mb).
Here is my code

Model BlobImage.cs

```
namespace ImageToDb.Models
{
    public class BlobImg
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public byte[] image { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ImageController.cs

```
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;

[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(IFormFile file, BlobImg bolb)
        {
            string fileName = string.Empty;
            string path = string.Empty;
            var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                
                using (var img = Image.Load(file.OpenReadStream()))
                {
                    string newSize = ResizeImage(img, 500, 500);
                    string[] aSize = newSize.Split(',');
                    img.Mutate(h => h.Resize(Convert.ToInt32(aSize[1]), Convert.ToInt32(aSize[0])));
                    
                    //This section save the image to database using blob
                    foreach (var item in files)
                    {
                        if (item.Length > 0)
                        {
                            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
                                bolb.image = stream.ToArray();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    
                }

               ;
            }
            return View();
        }

        public string ResizeImage(Image img, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
        {
            if (img.Width > maxWidth || img.Height > maxHeight)
            {
                double widthRatio = (double)img.Width / (double)maxWidth;
                double heightRatio = (double)img.Height / (double)maxHeight;
                double ratio = Math.Max(widthRatio, heightRatio);
                int newWidth = (int)(img.Width / ratio);
                int newHeight = (int)(img.Height / ratio);
                return newHeight.ToString() + "," + newWidth.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return img.Height.ToString() + "," + img.Width.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compress the image on this line:

```
img.Mutate(h => h.Resize(Convert.ToInt32(aSize[1]), Convert.ToInt32(aSize[0])));
```

Then you don't reference it again in any of subsequent code and (I assume) save everything in HttpContext.Request.Form.Files instead. Rather than doing this, save the "img" object to the database instead. I can't see any code which actually saves anything to the database regardless but I suspect this is the problem based on your description. So your code is most likely fine you're just saving the wrong thing.

Try this, you'll need to determine the image format yourself:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(IFormFile file, BlobImg bolb)
    {
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            
            using (var img = Image.Load(file.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                string newSize = ResizeImage(img, 500, 500);
                string[] aSize = newSize.Split(',');
                img.Mutate(h => h.Resize(Convert.ToInt32(aSize[1]), Convert.ToInt32(aSize[0])));

                //This section save the image to database using blob
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    img.Save(ms, imageFormat);
                    bolb.image = ms.ToArray();
                }   
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: above  my code after running, when I save the image  In database saving original image not the compressed one but I want to save  Compressed image.

Comment: Point out the line where you save the image to the database please?

Comment: that foreach area of index action.. I mension it on code..

Comment: The foreach area is making no reference to the "img" object which is what you need to save. You are saving the contents of "files" (which is "HttpContext.Request.Form.Files") instead of saving "img" which is your compressed image.

Comment: So if I call `var image= img.Mutate(h => h.Resize(Convert.ToInt32(aSize[1]), Convert.ToInt32(aSize[0])));` its getting error or call it direct `foreach(var item in img)` also getting error

Comment: I've updated my example with some more code. This may help explain what I mean.